# “It is true that smoking is bad. So is it that drinking is bad.”

Tags: conjunctions, metaphors

> It is true that smoking is bad. So is it that drinking is bad.

Is this construction possible?

Comment: Your second sentence is wrong, but it looks like there are multiple things that you could have been trying to say there. What link between drinking being bad and smoking being bad are you trying to convey?

Comment: Yup. But it looks like *It is true that smoking is bad. So is it [true] that drinking is bad?* It only works as a question.

Comment: @mimsug And you can't ellipt the "true" in your version. The *It is* construction is used specifically to put "true" into the most emphatic position, so leaving it out sounds very odd.

Comment: Please use specific question titles.

Answer (score 7):

*So is/does X*, meaning *X is/does the same*, can only be used when *X* is the subject of a proposition.

> Smoking is bad. So is drinking.

But the construction *It is true that [Y]* represents

> [Y] is true.

*It* is not a "real" subject but  a "dummy" subject, only put in so *[Y]* can be postponed until after *true*. Consequently *it* cannot serve as the subject of *so is/does X*. You have to say:

> It is true that smoking is bad. It is also true that drinking is bad.